# How to make Excel cell a combobox using c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have been searching the net but couldn't find a way to turn a cell into a combobox ( or dropdown as they seem to be called sometimes )? I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 14.0 ( Runtime version 2.0.50727).

Comment: What does the VBA look like for this?  I've had success with some of the more complex stuff in Excel Interop by recording a VBA macro of the action, and then using the same approach via .NET.

Comment: When I go to the developer tab and click on View Code I cannot see any VBA code in my reference sheet. Honestly I don't how this sheet was created. I uploaded a screenshot of the combo box I like to recreate with C#. http://imgur.com/xMCymTc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution of what I tried to achieve:

```
Excel.Application App = null;
Excel.Workbook Book = null;

Excel.Worksheet Sheet = null;

object Missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

try
{
    App = new Excel.Application();
    Book = App.Workbooks.Add();

    Sheet = (Excel.Worksheet) Book.Worksheets[1];

    Excel.Range Range = Sheet.get_Range("B2", "B2");

    Range.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList
        , Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop
        , Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween
        , "Item1,Item2,Item3"
        , Type.Missing);
    Range.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
    Range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 217, 217, 0)); 

    App.Visible = true;
}
finally
{
    Base.ReleaseObject(Sheet);
    Base.ReleaseObject(Book);
    Base.ReleaseObject(App);
}
```

Comment: In my case this worked only when using `;` as an item separator, not `,`. Additionally, I had to call `Range.Validation.Delete` before `Range.Validation.Add` to avoid an exception from VSTO.

Comment: @MarekDzikiewicz: This happens if your locale settings use a comma as a decimal seperator, then you need to use ;

Answer (score 1):

Well, an Excel hostable .Net combobox definitely exists.
Is the example code in the post helpful?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259140(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259140%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Private Sub ExcelRangeAddComboBox()

    Dim ComboBox1 As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel. _
        Controls.ComboBox = Me.Controls.AddComboBox( _
        Me.Range("A1", "B1"), "ComboBox1")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("First Item")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Second Item")
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub
```

If you'rr not familiar with developing add-ins, the following might help to get you started:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442981(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442981%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

and the videos here were very helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh133459

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Can I use this code in a normal WinForm application?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe so (but I could always be wrong!)  In my experience everything VSTO related is a .Net wrapper for office specific com objects.  The closest you could get is to embed an excel instance in your winforms form. See this blog post for example.  http://wblo.gs/Z5O  just remember that the end user must have Excel installed.  Barring that it may be worth looking into 3rd party "Excel Like" controls.